# Redirect Port 80 request to 443 for site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I managed to redirect my requests from port 80 to 443 using the redirect permanent.

However, there is a problem. On my page there is a link to `/forum/`. When one clicks the link it tries to go to `https://futureretrogaming.comforum` with no slashes.

What can be done about this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin kevin.miller@futureretrogaming.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/frg"
    ServerName www.futureretrogaming.com
    ServerAlias futureretrogaming.com
    ServerAlias futureretrogaming.net
    ServerAlias www.futureretrogaming.net
    ErrorLog "/var/www/frg/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/frg/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/frg>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
    Redirect permanent / https://futureretrogaming.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mod_rewrite` instead of a simple `Redirect`. First, make sure your Apache setup has `mod_write` enabled by running this command; this works for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart Apache; again this works for Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And your server should now be able to handle `mod_write` instructions. So adjust your virtual host config like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin kevin.miller@futureretrogaming.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/frg"
    ServerName www.futureretrogaming.com

    ServerAlias futureretrogaming.com
    ServerAlias futureretrogaming.net
    ServerAlias www.futureretrogaming.net

    ErrorLog "/var/www/frg/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/frg/log/access.log" common

    <Directory /var/www/frg>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    // Redirect permanent / https://futureretrogaming.com/
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

If you notice I commented out the `Redirect` you had in place & added some spacing for readability. And you can check this from the command line using `curl -I` like this:

```
curl -I http://futureretrogaming.com/forum
```

And the results I see right now show this working:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 02:03:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://futureretrogaming.com/forum
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Somewhat unrelated but since I am noticing it, you can also make your life a bit easier by consolidating & simplifying some of the `ServerAlias` stuff:

```
ServerAlias futureretrogaming.com
ServerAlias futureretrogaming.net
ServerAlias www.futureretrogaming.net
```

Instead of 3 lines that could be all consolidated into one line:

```
ServerAlias futureretrogaming.* www.futureretrogaming.*
```

The wildcard covers all top level domains such as `.com`, `.net` & even `.org` as well as others.

Comment: It says RewriteEngine is an invalid command

Comment: @Kyle Your server probably needs to have `mod_rewrite` enabled. Will update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, how do I enable mod_rewrite is that just a apt-get install deal?

Comment: @Kyle Nope. No need to run `apt-get unstall`. Please read my recent edit near the top of the answer. If you are on Ubuntu/Debian then simply run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then run `sudo service apache2 restart` & you should be set for this configuration to work.

Comment: https://futureretrogaming.comforum/ is still what is happening

Comment: @Kyle This should work. Be sure you are not caching a browser response. Also, check from the terminal using: `curl -I http://futureretrogaming.com/forum`. I see it as working. Check my edit to see the output of `curl -I` as I am seeing it.

Comment: Naturally I don't have curl. Okay after clearing cache it does work. Wish I get my browser to stop doing that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kyle Hey, all good. If you login to your Ubuntu server (I assume) you can run that `curl -I` from the command line as well to confirm. But glad it’s all fixed now.